# Как делать посты типа "текст + картинка" в vk_api python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Нужно со своей страницы на открытой стене паблика сделать пост, содержащий текст и картинку. Сделать это нужно с vk_api на python. Я проверил документацию, погуглил, но конкретного ответа не нашел.
Заранее благодарен

Comment: [wall.post](https://vk.com/dev/wall.post), обратите внимание на права

Comment: @nomnoms12, можешь скинуть готовую строку кода, просто там нет примера, а собирать инфу по кускам довольно сложно

Answer (score 0):

Вызываете метод wall.post, с авторизацией через пользователя. Примерно так это должно выглядеть:

```
    vk.wall.post(
owner_id = <ID пользователя или сообщества>, 
message = <Сообщение>, 
attachments = <Вложения>)
```

Атрибутов у данного метода куча, посмотрите в официальной документации VK API нужные Вам. Тут и "собирать инфу по кускам" не нужно, все элементарно делается.

Comment: вы бы привели больше информации, для решению ссылки на документацию, и более конкретные примеры